# Listing failed - TeX Live Utility

Tags: mactex, ctan, update, texlive-2020

From a couple of days when I try to update the packages with the TeX Live Utility I get the message: Listing Failed.
The Repository's URL is
http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
Going directly to this address with a browser I got error 404 Not Found and I realized that the CTAN word in the web site is lowercase, i.e. ctan.
Changing the Home Repository did not work properly.
Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: well you will have to switch to another repository. This one looks down.

Comment: There is an up-to-date-list here: https://www.ctan.org/mirrors
Then do this `tlmgr option repository <insert-mirror-here>/systems/texlive/tlnet/` and you should be good to go!

Comment: I generate the list of URLs for TeX Live Utility by parsing [CTAN's site list](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/CTAN.sites), but it only gets updated when I release a new version. However, the only change in the next version would be from http to https, so CTAN's list is wrong. If you're seeing a problem with setting the home repository manually, please file a bug report with instructions to reproduce the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @phil-elkabat I am still getting the error `Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /usr/local/texlive/2018/ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet/!`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GARR mirror (the one for Italy) appears unresponsive to the queries by `tlmgr`, although it appears up-to-date. If you set the repository to

http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet

then you'll be redirected to a working mirror according to some rule of “vicinity”. My queries to `tlmgr` are presently redirected to

http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/

which is located in Slovenia.

Comment: The Tex Live Utility points to http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet whereas the garr mirror is http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet

Comment: @AlbyStalks I guess they changed the case a few days ago, because it used to be `CTAN`